# Cannot authenticate with Graph API access token on proprietary API

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to use the AD services to authenticate from a react app and send the token to my .Net Core to use the [Authorize] attribute, but as I could figure, the token I get here is just for authenticating into the Graph API.

Is there any way to get a token to use as "auth" header to call my API ?

JS:

```
this.userAgentApplication = new UserAgentApplication(config.appId, null, null); 

var access_token = this.userAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent(config.scopes);
```

Then i get the access_token and send to my backend as an "Authorization" header with the value "Bearer ${access_token}"

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify that you want an access token for your API through `config.scopes`.

You can use e.g.

```
api-client-id-here/.default
```

Or instead of .default you can specify a scope you have defined on the API.
You can specify multiple of them if you want multiple scopes.

Comment: I was using MSAL on the React app, now I'm using ADAL and I could authenticate into mine API. The question now is how to retrieve some adittional claims from the AD. eg.: extensionAttribute6

Comment: You can get those from MS Graph API I think. It might also be possible with the claims customization option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims